# Event Delegation Pattern with addEventListener and nested elements in buttons

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a set of buttons in a parent.  Each containing an SVG icon which are added programmatically.  I'm attempting to listen on the parent element and then use event delegation to trigger different functionality for particular buttons, but what lands up happening is I get event targets of the contained svg's or paths rather than the buttons themselves.  Is there a way to leverage event bubbling, or change the way I'm doing this to still avoid adding a ton of event handlers, and trigger the events I need?  Here's some simplified code:

```
<div class="parent">
    // I have a whole lot of these added to the page programmatically
    <button class="some-unique-class">
        <svg> //... </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

and then in my JavaScript :

```
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    //.. I always want to trigger events on the buttons, not
    // on the svg's and their paths.  
});
```

Using JQuery I'm able to do this easily, by listening on a parent element and then specifying the element, but I'd like to do this in vanilla JS.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You basically always have to check whether the target is a child node of the button when using event delegation.

Comment: I assumed as much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the simplest way would be to have a function like jquery's `closest`:

```js
function closest(elem, selector) {
  do {
    if(elem.matches(selector)) return elem;
    elem = elem.parentNode;
  } while(elem);
}


document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  var btn = closest(e.target, 'button');
  btn.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <button class="some-unique-class">
        <b>hey</b>
    </button>
    <button class="some-unique-class">
        <b>hey</b>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: okay, I thought so, is this the standard way?  I noticed that the target also contains a path object that contains each element it bubbles through back to the document, so I as thinking of attempting to use that.

Comment: `closest` is built-in.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest Documentation of built-in (which wasn't when answer was written) but is now, so use it :).